# tastypie returns duplicate object when using limit offset

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-orm

I'm using the following resource in tastypie:

```
class ChoiceResource(LtgModelWithUuidResource):
    """
    Resource for the choice model
    """
    explanation = fields.ForeignKey(MultiLangTextFieldResource,attribute='explanation',full=True,null=True,
                                    use_in=DisableOnPatch())
    question = fields.ForeignKey('ltg_backend_app.base.api.question.QuestionResource',attribute='question',
                                 use_in=DisableOnPatch())
    keywords = fields.ManyToManyField(XrayResource,attribute='keywords',null=True,
                                      use_in=DisableOnPatch())
    
    class Meta(LtgResource.Meta):
        queryset = Choice.objects.select_related('explanation','question').\
            all().prefetch_related('keywords')

        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        order_by = ['id',]
```

***THE PROBLEM :***

When querying for

> api/v1/choice/?limit=100&offset=200

a choice with **`id = 615`** is included in the results.

When querying for

> api/v1/choice/?limit=100&offset=2400

the choice with **`id = 615`** is returning **AGAIN**

- The `total_count` returning by the api is correct (6010 objects).

***THE POSSIBLE CAUSE:***

When inspecting the generated SQL query, There is no `ORDER BY` in the generated SQL, however there are `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` set.

Quoting the **Postgresql** Documentation:

> When using `LIMIT`, it is a good idea to use an `ORDER BY` clause that constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get an unpredictable subset of the query's rows---you may be asking for the tenth through twentieth rows, but tenth through twentieth in what ordering? The ordering is unknown, unless you specified `ORDER BY`.
>
> The query optimizer takes `LIMIT` into account when generating a query plan, so you are very likely to get different plans (yielding different row orders) depending on what you give for `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Thus, using different `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` values to select different subsets of a query result will give inconsistent results unless you enforce a predictable result ordering with `ORDER BY`. This is not a bug; it is an inherent consequence of the fact that SQL does not promise to deliver the results of a query in any particular order unless `ORDER BY` is used to constrain the order.

***THE SOLUTION I'VE FOUND:***

I've added `order_by` to the queryset, and now it looks like this:

```
Choice.objects.select_related('explanation','question').\
        all().prefetch_related('keywords').order_by('id)
```

***THE QUESTION:***

- Im not sure if I missing something here, or what I'm doing wrong.
  Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
- As I see it, I shouldn't include the `order_by` on the django queryset or in the url query params for it to work, or at least it's not specified in the tastypie docs.

Thanks.

Comment: You do need to order the queryset. It's usually enough to set [`Meta.ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering).

Comment: Good tip. Still conflicting though regarding the fact that you can use the pagination without ordering and no warning appear in the code nor the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The ID usually starts with 1. However this is not always the case. Regardless, the default sorting would be in the order it was inserted, so this is expected behavior.

If you would like to override this you can, like previously mentioned, set the `ordering` parameter in the `Media` class. Or also you can pass in `order_by` in the GET query.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you need an `.order_by` in the Queryset because the field `id` is not part of the Tastypie resource; only the Django Model.
Ref: [Tastypie source](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/a02d9317126a5e83daee687c05a445086f25bf71/tastypie/resources.py#L2117)

In *general*, it is a good practice to order your fields as close to the data as possible. If the field exists in the Django Model - order it using the queryset allowing an optimal SQL call. But if the field is computed on the Tastypie resource then let Tastypie's `order_by` handle it.